# Modify a PCAP file using Perl with checksum update

Tags: perl, pcap

I have some 250MB pcap. I have able to change MAC and IP address' using tcpreplay but I also need to modify some fields inside the packet payload. If I change the field by reading as a binary the checksum of the ip payload will fail. Is there a module that will allow me to modify certain fields and the checksum will be updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Net::PCap to parse such files: http://search.cpan.org/~kcarnut/Net-Pcap-0.05/Pcap.pm

Here is an example: http://hype-free.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/parsing-pcap-files-with-perl.html

```
use Net::TcpDumpLog;
use NetPacket::Ethernet;
use NetPacket::IP;
use NetPacket::TCP;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $log = Net::TcpDumpLog->new(); 
$log->read("foo.pcap");

foreach my $index ($log->indexes) { 
  my ($length_orig, $length_incl, $drops, $secs, $msecs) = $log->header($index); 
  my $data = $log->data($index);

  my $eth_obj = NetPacket::Ethernet->decode($data);    
  next unless $eth_obj->{type} == NetPacket::Ethernet::ETH_TYPE_IP;

  my $ip_obj = NetPacket::IP->decode($eth_obj->{data});
  next unless $ip_obj->{proto} == NetPacket::IP::IP_PROTO_TCP;

  my $tcp_obj = NetPacket::TCP->decode($ip_obj->{data});
  my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime($secs + $msecs/1000);
  print sprintf("%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d.%d", 
    $mon, $mday, $hour, $min, $sec, $msecs), 
    " ", $eth_obj->{src_mac}, " -> ", 
    $eth_obj->{dest_mac}, "\n";    
  print "\t", $ip_obj->{src_ip}, ":", $tcp_obj->{src_port}, 
    " -> ", 
    $ip_obj->{dest_ip}, ":", $tcp_obj->{dest_port}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: This is great! NetPacket looks like the right module for this job. Thanks!

Comment: Actually. I'm working with tunneled IP packets so I'm actually looking to go past the protocol TCP/UDP header. I'm hoping to do 1. strip the packet past the UDP header. 2. Do a search for a particular pattern and replace with a different pattern. Will the NetPacket module allow me to do that and still be able to update all the chekcsums upon re-assembly?

Comment: Sorry, this a too specified question and I do not able to answer it.

Comment: thanks, i think have solution. I'm using bbe to change the pattern and then use the module to update all chksums, it seems to be working ok

Comment: Fast forward 6 years to the original post, I have ended up using both Python Scapy as well as C++'s PcapPlusPlus libs to achieve this, its a lot easier now than 6 years ago